# Java calling of class method, "incompatible types" inside called method

Tags: java, string, methods, boolean

/** from my main class and method */

```
String ans = null;
    System.out.println("Has your address changed?(y/n): " );
    ans = input.next();
    munozAccount.changeAddress(ans);
```

/**from accounting class called by main method
message says required: boolean found: java.lang.String */

```
public void changeAddress(String ans) {
    if (ans = "y") {
        cust.changeStreet();
        cust.changeCity();
        cust.changeState();
        cust.changeZip();
    } else {
        System.out.print("understood");
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `if (ans = "y") {` to `if ("y".equals(ans)) {`.

Comment: `if (ans = "y")` That is very wrong.

Comment: @user2430297: Because `=` is **assignment**, not equality. `==` is equality, although with strings you actually want to use the `equals` method instead.

Comment: you want to assign something to a variable ans="y". You want to check for equality if(ans.equals("y")). A boolean is needed because the if statement is checking if the condition is true or false. You have used an assignment

Comment: @SLaks: Oh, not *very* wrong, surely? Quite a common error for folks new to the languages syntactically derived from B. Lots of languages happily use `=` for both, just not B, C, C++, Java, JavaScript, C#, D, ... :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: You mean `==`, don't you?

Comment: @SLaks: Ah, no, but I see why you thought that. I meant for both assignment and equality, not for equality and `equals`. (JavaScript, C#, and a few others are perfectly happy to compare strings with `==`...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: AFAIK, every language you listed doesn't.

Comment: @SLaks: I'm afraid you're mistaken. Again: Both JavaScript and C# are perfectly happy with it. Try this in your browser's JavaScript console: `var a = "foo"; "foo" == a;` (or perhaps, just to be sure, `a == "f" + "o" + "o"`.) It shows `true`. And similarly in C#. **Not** in C, which doesn't have strings, C++, or Java. I wouldn't have a clue about B, and I don't remember much D. :-)

Comment: @SLaks: No. Go read again. "Lots of languages happily use `=` for both" and "just ***not*** B, C, C++, Java, JavaScript, C#, D..." Any BASIC, for instance, happily uses `=` for both assignment and equality.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Now I get it; I thought you said "not **just**".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used the assignment operator `=` in this line:

```
if (ans = "y") {
```

... and the resultant type is a `String`, but a `boolean` is required for the `if` statement, hence the error.

Use the [`equals` method of `String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) to compare string values, which will return a `boolean`:

```
if ("y".equals(ans)) {
```

The `"y"` goes first to avoid a `NullPointerException` that would result if you had said `ans.equals("y")` and `ans` was `null`.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that `==` is the equality operator, even though of course you wouldn't use it here.